# Drawing on a "dynamic" canvas

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, canvas, draw

So I have a loop that creates canvas according to certain parameters from jquery.
Here's the code:

```
var Game = {
    cards: [],
    $board: $('[data-display="game-board"]'),

    deal: function() {
     var self = this;
     var dealRequest = $.ajax({
        url: 'set.php?action=deal',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            self.cards = data;
            self.displayCards.call(self);
            self.existingSet(data);
            self.setCardListeners();
            self.setPageListeners();
        }
     });
   },

    displayCards: function() {
     var self = this;
     $.each(this.cards, function(index, card) {
       var cardNode = $('<div>');
       cardNode.addClass('card');
       $(cardNode).data({
         'id': card.id,
         'shape': card.shape,
         'fill': card.fill,
         'color': card.color,
         'number': card.number
       });
     
   var shapeNode = $("<canvas></canvas>");
   shapeNode.addClass('shape ' + card.color + ' ' + card.shape + ' ' + card.fill);

   for (var i = 0; i < card.number; i++) {
     cardNode.append(shapeNode.clone());
   }
   self.$board.append(cardNode);
    
   // display 4 cards per row
   if ((index+1) % 3 === 0) {
    self.$board.append($('<div>'));
   }
};
```

Then I try to recover from my HTML these canvas created using the name of the css classes, with something like:

```
var canvases = document.getElementsByClassName('shape diamond red solid');
```

But when I try to draw in these canvas there is nothing displayed. I do something like:

```
var canvases = document.getElementsByClassName('shape red diamond solid');
for (let canvas of canvases) {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    drawDiamond(context, 50, 50, 75, 100);
    canvas.fillStyle("#FF0000");
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

But when I create a canvas statically that works.

Can you please try to help me to find the problem or maybe a solution? Thank you!

Comment: I do not see where you append the canvas to the document, so it's not an element you can "get".

Comment: I am still a beginner in javascript I know very little about it. Could you show me how to do it please?

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest the following code:

```
$.each(this.cards, function(index, card) {
  var cardNode = $('<div>', {
    class: "card"
  }).appendTo("body");
  cardNode.data(card);
  var shapeNode = $('<canvas>', {
    class: "shape " + card.color + " " + card.shape + " " + card.fill
  }).appendTo(cardNode);
});
```

The once that is done the following should work:

```
var canvases = $('.shape.red.diamond.solid');

canvases.each(function(i, c) {
    var context = c.getContext('2d');

    drawDiamond(context, 50, 50, 75, 100);
    c.fillStyle("#FF0000");
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
});
```

**Update**

Consider the following.

```js
var Game = {
  cards: [],
  $board: $('[data-display="game-board"]'),
  deal: function() {
    var self = this;
    /*
    $.getJSON('set.php?action=deal', function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(i, card) {
        self.cards.push(card);
      });
      self.displayCards();
      self.existingSet(data);
      self.setCardListeners();
      self.setPageListeners();
    });
    */
    self.cards.push({
      id: "ace-spade",
      shape: "spade",
      fill: "solid",
      color: "black",
      number: 1
    });
    self.displayCards();
  },
  displayCards: function() {
    var self = this;
    if (self.cards.length == 0) {
      return false;
    }
    $.each(self.cards, function(index, card) {
      var cardNode = $('<div>', {
        class: "card"
      }).appendTo(self.$board);
      cardNode.data({
        'id': card.id,
        'shape': card.shape,
        'fill': card.fill,
        'color': card.color,
        'number': card.number
      });

      for (var i = 0; i < card.number; i++) {
        cardNode.append($("<canvas>", {
          class: 'shape ' + card.color + ' ' + card.shape + ' ' + card.fill
        }));
      }
      self.$board.append(cardNode);

      // display 4 cards per row
      if ((index + 1) % 3 === 0) {
        self.$board.append($('<div>'));
      }
    });
  }
};

Game.deal();
```

```css
.card {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 175px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-display="game-board"></div>
```

I cannot test with AJAX, so I populated the "deck" with an Ace of Spades. The resulting HTML is:

```
<div data-display="game-board">
  <div class="card">
    <canvas class="shape black spade solid"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont know why but it's not working. Also when i do   console.log(canvases)    there is nothing displayed.

Comment: @redkoo then you will need to provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @redkoo I updated my answer. Without a proper exmaple, I cannot completely address your question. Hope that sets you in the right direction. If it addresses this one part, you can mark it as the answer (and upvote). If you need more help after, you may consider opening a new question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a  last question: When I try to do the $.getJSON it doesn't display my shape beacause when i do  var canvases = $('.shape'); it still empty but when i push a card statically it works. What do you think about it?

Comment: @redkoo not able to follow what you mean. If my answer addresses your initial question, please mark it and upvote.I would advise working on it further and if needed, post a new question of the new issue.